# Lying to the dying - are Kant and utilitarians bound to disagree?

Tags: history-of-philosophy

Suppose a situation in which a woman tells her dying father that she will not marry outside her religion. She is lying to him in order to save his feelings. Are Kant and utilitarians committed by their different ethical theories to disagree over the moral permissibility of the lie ?

Comment: You have another answer to your question about lying.

Comment: 'Utilitarianism' is too broad a term, and there are too many varieties of utilitarianism, for the question to be answered in moderate space. Also the example is very lightly described, which makes a utilitarian analysis of any kind very difficult. Close the question, and start again.